# Is it possible to create Rack middleware with a module entry point rather than a class?

Tags: namespaces, rack, middleware

I've been creating some Rack middleware, which works perfectly, except that I'm not happy with the way my gem is structured.

In my sinatra app I require the middleware like:

```
use MyProjectNamespace::MyMiddlewareClass, &config
```

which is great, but the problem is I would rather reference a second namespace rather than a class such as:

```
use MyProjectNamespace::MyMiddlewareNamespace, &config
```

but if I use a module for MyMiddlewareNamespace, then rack complains with:

> MyMiddlewareNamespace is not a class (TypeError)

the problem is that I've got multiple gems under MyProjectNamespace, and I want to separate their namespaces, so that I can have something like:

```
module MyProjectNamespace::MyMiddlewareNamespace::Helpers
  class SomeHelper
  end
end

module MyProjectNamespace::AnotherMiddlewareNamespace::Helpers
  class SomeHelper
  end
end
```

Is there a way to do this with rack middleware? Ruby doesn't allow modules to have the same name as a class name.

Answer (score 0):

In your case, it looks like the methods (initialize, call) are defined on SomeHelper, not on the namespace. In that case, pass in the class name, not the module name:

```
use MyProjectNamespace::MyMiddlewareNamespace::SomeHelper, &config
```

However, if the problem is that you want initialize and call to be in a module, first you should include that module into a class, then pass in the class.

You can do the same thing with an instance -- create an instance, tell it to use the module (via include or extend) and pass that to Sinatra's "use" instead of passing the module directly.

The problem is that Rack wants to instantiate whatever you give it. Classes are instantiable, modules aren't.

Comment: thanks for your answer Noah. It was the case that I wanted my module to have the initialize, call methods (which I'm aware is just not going to happen...) 

Probably quite unique to my situation, but what I ended up doing was having just one middleware instead of 3, and passing the other two as config arguments - effectively creating middleware for my middleware. Again, probably unique to my situation.

Comment: Rails does something a bit like that with controllers. But fair enough.

Comment: And I'd still recommend creating classes or instances that use the module in that case. Though if you're happy with your code, ignore me. Working code trumps dogma ;-)